# Flag review bug: "undefined"

Tags: bug, review, flags

A very minor bug appeared when I used the flag review tool today for the first time ever.

[image: Screenshot showing confusing text "undefined more votes needed"]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open flag review, select question
2. Vote to close the question
3. Attempt to flag the question

I believe it should state a number (instead of "undefined") for how many more votes are needed, and it should show the action (putting the flag you assigned a moment before) as completed.

Comment: @Mat why not choose the end of the dupe chain?

Comment: I apologize for posting a duplicate (will be more careful in future) but the two earlier questions do not have an answer, either.

Comment: True, but there are ways to bring attention back to old questions like editing and bounties. No need to apologize, no harm done.